# Ubuntu 22.04 unable to communicate with scanner

Tags: scanner, epson

i know there are a lot of question about setting up epson scanners on ubuntu but i tried
for days now and i cannot get it fixed - so here is my setup and problem:

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS, 64-bit

**#I installed this driver bundle from epson via shell script:**
epsonscan2-bundle-6.6.42.0.x86_64.deb

**#if i use ImageScan for Linux 2.30.4 the scanner works fine -

**#but if i try to scan now with Epson Scan 2 i get:
Unable to communicate with the scanner. Make sure the scanner is connected to the computer and turned on.

**#and with Document Scan:**
Unable to connect to Scanner.

**#i tried to find the scanner via terminal and i think its fine:**

**#sudo sane-find-scanner**

sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.
No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found possible USB scanner (vendor=0x147e [UPEK], product=0x2016 [Biometric Coprocessor]) at libusb:001:003
found possible USB scanner (vendor=0x04b8 [EPSON], product=0x0130 [EPSON Scanner]) at libusb:001:006
Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

Not checking for parallel port scanners.

Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
can't be detected by this program.

**#sudo scanimage -L**

Created directory: /var/lib/snmp/cert_indexes

device `escl:[http://192.168.0.142:8080'](http://192.168.0.142:8080%27) is a HP ENVY 5530 series [D3AB79] platen scanner

device `epsonscan2:EPSON Scanner:001:006:esci2:usb:ES007C:304' is a EPSON EPSON

Scanner:001:006 flatbed scanner

device `epkowa:interpreter:001:006' is a Epson Perfection V500 flatbed scanner

device `hpaio:/net/envy_5530_series?ip=192.168.0.142&queue=false' is a Hewlett-Packard

envy_5530_series all-in-one

device `airscan:e0:HP ENVY 5530 series [D3AB79]' is a eSCL HP ENVY 5530 series [D3AB79]

ip=192.168.0.142, 2a02:810d:980:1870:727a:ac6e:8e61:8de5

**#i read a post about setting up a scanner group but it doesnt tell me how and i dont know #if its my problem ?!**

**#when i list up my groups i get these results:**

thymolect@Thymolector:~/Downloads/epsonscan2-bundle-6.6.42.0.x86_64.deb$ groups

thymolect adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare

**#thymolect@Thymolector:~/Downloads/epsonscan2-bundle-6.6.42.0.x86_64.deb$ cat /etc/group**

root:x:0:

daemon:x:1:

bin:x:2:

sys:x:3:

adm:x:4:syslog,thymolect

tty:x:5:

disk:x:6:

lp:x:7:

mail:x:8:

news:x:9:

uucp:x:10:

man:x:12:

proxy:x:13:

kmem:x:15:

dialout:x:20:

fax:x:21:

voice:x:22:

cdrom:x:24:thymolect

floppy:x:25:

tape:x:26:

sudo:x:27:thymolect

audio:x:29:pulse

dip:x:30:thymolect

www-data:x:33:

backup:x:34:

operator:x:37:

list:x:38:

irc:x:39:

src:x:40:

gnats:x:41:

shadow:x:42:

utmp:x:43:

video:x:44:

sasl:x:45:

plugdev:x:46:thymolect

staff:x:50:

games:x:60:

users:x:100:

nogroup:x:65534:

systemd-journal:x:101:

systemd-network:x:102:

systemd-resolve:x:103:

crontab:x:104:

messagebus:x:105:

systemd-timesync:x:106:

input:x:107:

sgx:x:108:

kvm:x:109:

render:x:110:

syslog:x:111:

tss:x:112:

bluetooth:x:113:

ssl-cert:x:114:

uuidd:x:115:

systemd-oom:x:116:

tcpdump:x:117:

_ssh:x:118:

avahi-autoipd:x:119:

netdev:x:120:

avahi:x:121:

lpadmin:x:122:thymolect

rtkit:x:123:

whoopsie:x:124:

sssd:x:125:

nm-openvpn:x:126:

scanner:x:127:saned

saned:x:128:

colord:x:129:

geoclue:x:130:

pulse:x:131:

pulse-access:x:132:

gdm:x:133:

lxd:x:134:thymolect

thymolect:x:1000:

sambashare:x:135:thymolect

**#Can anyone help me plz ?!**

thanks <3

Comment: Forget about adding yourself to the scanner group; I assure you it is unneeded. See https://wiki.debian.org/Scanner

Answer (score 0):

When I input *Perfection V500* at

http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX

I get to download

iscan-gt-x770-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz

Perhaps you can try to install and use this package.

Comment: i installed it already - still im able to select two different usb ports for the scanner "001:006" or via epkowa "epkowa:interpreter001:003", but esponscan 2 cant communicate to the scanner on both ports

Answer (score 0):

EPSON's iscan software and plugins used to work for Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04, but EPSON seems to have consolidated (read: "broken") the older efforts.

**EDIT / Disclaimer:** *I figured, the OP's question is on an USB-attached scanner. I only verified the solution for network scanning. Please try for yourself.*

As of today, to make the scanner work you might be able to find the (non-free) scanner plugin for download on the EPSON website.

1. Go to the [Epson Download Center website](https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) (in doubt, search the Web as the URL seems to change).
2. Search for your printer/scanner/MFP model and select "Linux" for Operating System.
3. Download the scanner driver archive (e.g. "Epson Scan 2") from the result page.
4. Unzip the downloaded `.tar.gz` file (e.g. `tar xfz ...`) and `cd` into the created folder with the same name as the downloaded file.
5. You'll find a `core/` and a `plugins/` folder that both include a `.deb` file you can install. The EPSON scan program is in the core folder (it doesn't detect the printer over the network for me, so of no use), for the GNOME Document Scanner you only need the Debian package in the plugins folder, e.g.

```
dpkg -i plugins/epsonscan2-non-free-plugin_1.0.0.6-1_amd64.deb
```

I can confirm this works for my EPSON WF-7710 MFP scanner to scan over the network. GNOME's Document Scanner shows two entries of detected scanners, though. The one shipped with Ubuntu ("Epson WF-7710 Series") makes the scanner time out, while the installed one ("eSCL EPSON WF-7710 Series") scans successfully.

*P.S.: Kudos to the TutorialForLinux website [where I found this information](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2023/02/04/how-to-download-epson-image-scan-software-for-ubuntu-22-04/), originally.*
*PPS: If you like Ansible you can use the `painless.software` [Ansible role](https://galaxy.ansible.com/painless/software) to install the driver ([source code](https://github.com/painless-software/ansible-role-software/blob/main/tasks/base/printers.yml)).*